# ¿Como hago para que react-native-image-picker no guarde imagen en álbum del dispositivo y solo la maneje a nivel de app?

Tags: react-native

¡Hola a todos!
He probado la  librería 'react-native-image-picker' para tomar una foto desde una app con RN, pero me guardan una copia de la imagen capturada en la galería del teléfono y solo necesito que se maneje a nivel de la app.
¿Alguien sabe qué biblioteca puedo ocupar o como configurar la librería de image-picker para que no guarde esa copia?

RN 0.61.4
Desarrollo de plataforma Android

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad por favor considera leer [ask], he de comentarte que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré encuenta para mis siguientes preguntas (Y)